# code showing empty dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.x, pysolr

I write the below code for my project but dataframe df showing empty records.I want to know where i am lacking in the code:

```
import urllib
from urllib2 import *
import pandas as pd
def urlmake(req):
    requests = [req]
    for parms in requests:
        url = 'http://localhost:8983/solr/data/select?indent=on&' + urllib.urlencode(parms)
        connection = urlopen(url)
        response = eval(connection.read())
        t = response['response']['numFound']
        req2 = req['q'][13:17]
        print(req2)
        if(req2 == 'AXIS'):
            print('true')
            for i in range(0,t):
                t1 = float((response['response']['docs'][i]['message']).split(" ")[1])
                #print(t1)
                t2 = response['response']['docs'][i]['customer_id']
                #print(t2)
                df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(t2,t1))




ba_query = [{'q':'sender_name:*AXIS*  AND message:*Avbl Lmt*','start':0,'rows':211,'wt':'json'}]


for i in range(0,len(ba_query)):
    urlmake(ba_query[i])
```

getting errror as:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'df' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: What output do you get when you run that code?

Comment: @Harlekuin i have edit my question

Comment: I meant the print()s as well but does David answer your question?

Comment: I have done earlier with my code  but give me error as: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'df' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    import urllib
    from urllib2 import *
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Customer_id','Spent'])
    def urlmake(req):
    requests = [req]
    for parms in requests:
        url = 'http://localhost:8983/solr/data/select?indent=on&' + urllib.urlencode(parms)
        connection = urlopen(url)
        response = eval(connection.read())
        t = response['response']['numFound']
        req2 = req['q'][13:17]
        print(req2)
        if(req2 == 'AXIS'):
            print('true')
            for i in range(0,t):
                t1 = float((response['response']['docs'][i]['message']).split(" ")[1])
                #print(t1)
                t2 = response['response']['docs'][i]['customer_id']
                #print(t2)
                df = df.append({'Customer_id':t2, 'Spent':t1}, ignore_index=True)  # HERE

See the comment in the code
```

.
Here's an MCVE of how your code should look:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame()

for iteration in range(0, 5):
    dummy_data = np.random.rand(3, 3)
    df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(dummy_data))

df.columns = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

New MCVE:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def myfunc():
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for iteration in range(0, 5):
        dummy_data = np.random.rand(3, 3)
        df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(dummy_data))
    df.columns = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    return df

df2 = myfunc()
print(df2)
```

Comment: It give me error as:    UnboundLocalError: local variable 'df' referenced before assignment

Comment: Try naming your columns after appending to your df.

Comment: @U8-Forward it resolve the problem of UnboundLocalError: local variable 'df' referenced before assignment but the dataframe is still empty

Comment: Please look at the MCVE.

Comment: Correct. You just need to add a 'df = pd.DataFrame()' above your 'def' which I forgot to put into my MCVE!

Comment: Otherwise should work. Check my updated MCVE to see what I mean. Basically you're creating an empty dataframe and you're adding data to the container.

Comment: Which error? Also copy my bottom block of code into your IDE and try it out

Comment: your code work correctly but when i performed on my code it giving me error as:local variable 'df' referenced before assignment

Comment: Oh I see. You changed your code and put in a function. Put the df = pd.DataFrame() right below def urlmake().

Comment: it is showing another error: DataFrame constructor not properly called! .

Comment: Just copy my second MCVE and build around it. In the spirit of learning, I would also suggest reading about local and global variables as it may help with your particular issues.

Comment: i want to ask if we have multiple records which are to be passed in the function then every time value of value of dataframe df  will changed because each time we are creating the dataframe so how can we preserve the value of df

Comment: Because df is defined locally inside the function. The variable df is destroyed every time your compiler reaches the end of the function body. Therefore I suggest not using a function. Again, this goes in line with reading about local and global variables.

Comment: Any alternative for this method so that this problem resolved